# How to pass parameters to a struts2-jquery Dialog with remote URL?

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am using struts2-jquery [Dialog Widget](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/DialogTag) to open a JSP page, which has a form to edit the Category.

Category contains two fields associated with it; name, and description.

I want to pass a `categoryId` to the JSP page so the form will prepopulate through `remoteurl`.

```html
<s:url id="cat1" var="remoteurl" action="editCategoryWindow"/>
<sj:dialog id="editCategoryDialog"
           autoOpen="false"
           height="auto"
           width="auto"
           modal="true"
           href="%{remoteurl}"
           title="Edit Category"/>
```

```js
function editCategory(categoryId) {
    $('#cat1').attr('categoryId');
    $('#editCategoryDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 500,
        width: 900
    });
    $('#editCategoryDialog').empty().data('categoryId', categoryId).dialog("open");
}
```

This doesn't work: there's a null pointer exception because there's no `categoryId` on the JSP page.

How should I pass the parameter to the JSP page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the URL with the category:

```html
<s:url id="cat1" var="remoteurl" action="editCategoryWindow">
  <s:param name="categoryId" value="%{whatever}"/>
</s:url>
```